# Кириллические URL`ы в AJAX-запросах.

Tags: javascript, кириллица

Здравствуйте.
Во всех ли браузерах (в "Chrome", впрочем, работает) будет работать код следующего вида?

```
var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
xmlhttp.open("GET", '/форум/ветки?страница=4&jx=1', true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) запрещает использовать в URI символы, не входящие в набор [`US-ASCII`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp) (т.е. разрешены только символы с кодами `0 - 127`). Но если выхотите использовать в URL'е кириллицу, то правильно будет такой URL привести к корректному ASCII формату - каждый кириллический символ заменить на знак процента с шестнадцатиричным кодом этого символа (используйте для этого JavaScript-функции [`encodeURI`](http://javascript.ru/encodeURI) или [`encodeURIComponent`](http://javascript.ru/encodeURIComponent)).

Когда выполняется такой запрос (без URL-кодировки, с кириллическими символами), то браузер, возможно, сам перекодирует URL в корректный формат. Chrome, да и любой уважающий себя браузер так делает. Но каждый браузер может делать это по-разному (небольшое исследование по теме, как раз подтверждающее это: [HTTP, RFC 3986 и браузеры](http://habrahabr.ru/post/68631/)). Поэтому, если вы хотите однозначности и корректной передачи параметров в URL'е с кириллическими символами, выполняйте кодировку вручную:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", encodeURI('/форум/ветки?страница=4&jx=1'), true);
```